# See the distinct Special Characters in a table

Tags: python

I am trying to find all the non-alphabet, non-numeric characters in a data table, what is the best way to do that in python?

I have tried the following

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

targe_table = results

if set(results).difference(ascii_letters + digits):
    print(ascii_letters + digits)
```

But this does not seem to work

Comment: *"this does not seem to work"* - is not a good problem statement. Are you getting errors? Wrong outputs? Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Comment: Also, what is a *"data table"*?